# How to create an Array[Any] containing integer values in scala?

Tags: scala

Update:
I had misunderstood an error message, so this question is invalid.

```
val inputIds = Array[Any](7, 1, 3)
```

is sufficient to create an Array[Any] in Scala.

===========

I'm trying to create an array that needs to be passed to a method that takes an Array[Any], but the values are numeric.

At first I tried just the normal way of creating an array:

```
val inputIds = Array(7, 1, 4)
```

and got the error:

```
Type mismatch, expected: Array[Any], actual: Array[Int]
```

(from the IntelliJ editor, I guess I haven't checked if it's correct)

Then I tried creating Integer values directly, e.g. by:

```
Integer.getInteger("7")
```

and passing those into the Array constructor, but I kept getting the same error.

Now I tried:

```
val inputIds: Array[Any] = Array[Any](7, 1, 4)
```

and it gave me:

```
Type mismatch, expected: Array[Any], actual: Array[Array[Int]]
```

As you can tell I'm going a bit spare, all I want is wrapper types and not primitives! I guess Scala is trying to optimize the array for iteration, but all I need is a tiny array I can pass to a var args taking arrays of mixed type.. Or maybe a better way of creating that vararg method?? Right now its type is:

```
Array[Any]*
```

========

Okay, so I got my original question resolved (though there's still a dispute in the comments over whether I correctly understood why the error was being caused). However, it didn't solve my problem, which is the following:

I am trying to transpose an array of arrays with different types (some are nested, but ultimately either Double or Ints) and can't figure out how to get the scala type system to do it. Here's the basic example:

```
val integerArray = Array(7, 1, 4)
val nestedIntegerArray = Array(
  Array(6, 10, 60),
  Array(5, 89, 57),
  Array(15, 3, 5)
)
val nestedDoubleArray = Array(
  Array(.13, .9, .8),
  Array(.2, .777, .57),
  Array(.15, .3, .5)
)

val brokenComputation = typeErrorExample(integerArray, nestedIntegerArray, nestedDoubleArray)
```

where the method being called is:

```
  private def typeErrorExample(arrays: Array[_ <: Any]*)={
    val arrayDataFrame = Array(arrays).transpose
  }
```

This gives the error:

```
No implicit view available from Seq[Array[_]] => Array[U].
[INFO]     val arrayDataFrame = Array(arrays).transpose
```

What's the right way to do this? Should I use a non-array data structure instead?

Hopefully having more of the code will help the experts understand what was causing my original error too. (inputIds was renamed to integerArray for consistency).

Comment: `val inputIds: Array[Any] = Array[Any](7, 1, 4)` works fine for me.  Are you sure that's what you tried?

Comment: @JoePallas Yes, I copy-pasted the code. Just tried actually compiling it and it gives this error:

[INFO]  found   : Array[Array[Int]]
[INFO]  required: Array[Any]
[INFO] Note: Array[Int] <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T.
[INFO] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)

Comment: The question is confused. A method that takes `Array[Any]` as an argument will accept an `Array[Int]` without error.

Comment: @jwvh Updated my question with a larger code snippet which might clarify something for you.

Comment: Post a [mcve] of `Array[Any](7, 1, 4)` failing, if it fails.

Comment: Please post the expected output for a given input. It's not at all obvious what `Array[Seq[Array[Any]]].transpose` should do.

Comment: @user2357112 I couldn't get a minimal example to fail, I assume I misread the error message. I would delete this question but StackOverflow won't let me.

Comment: @jwvh I'm not sure why you think I *want* the type to be Array[Seq[Array[Any]]] instead of Array[Array[Any]]] when I specifically said in the question that I was trying to transpose an array of arrays but couldn't get the type system to do it, but the output should be an array of arrays where the first entry of the outer array is Array(7, (6, 10, 60), (.13, .9, .8)).

Comment: It might not be what you _want_ (it obviously isn't) but that's what your code _does_ (`Array(arrays).transpose`). That's why expected output for a given input can be useful. Trying to understand what you _want_, but reading your code, is leading me astray.

Comment: @user2357112 Verified that I was mis-interpreting the error message... Array[Integer](7, 1, 4) was enough to fix the original error message, it became a similar one on Array[Array[Int]] b/c the *next* argument passed in has the same problem just at a deeper level of nesting.

Comment: @jwvh Sorry, I assumed that this was an obvious beginner's type error and that you were being sarcastic to punish me for posting such a basic question. IntelliJ doesn't give an error here so I assume it's making the same type error as I am mentally, as someone who's been using scala for about 2 days and 2 hours at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly casting is not ideal,  but should do the trick.

```
 Array(1, 2, 3).asInstanceOf[Array[Any]]
```

Answer (score 1):

@Adair, this appears to arrange the input arrays into the `Array[Array[Any]]` type that you're looking for.

```
def transpose(arrays: Array[_]*) :Array[Array[_]] =
  arrays.indices.map(x => arrays.map(_(x)).toArray).toArray
```

Now here's a word of advice: **DON'T DO IT**.

- It's unsafe. This will throw an exception if the number of arrays passed exceeds the dimensions of each array.
- Type `Any` is not what you want. When a data element becomes type `Any` then you've lost type information and it's a royal pain trying to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Jason's answer works, so does doing what the compiler error suggests when I ran it outside of intelliJ and changing the datatype in the method signature:

```
arrays: Array[_ <: Any]*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> Array(1, 2, 3).map(_.asInstanceOf[Any])
res6: Array[Any] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers which are correct. But why even need to do `asInstanceOf`. You can do it easily.

```
scala> val arr: Array[Any] = Array(1,2,3)
arr: Array[Any] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Simple, Work is done.